# Where can I find the original Arabic version of bin Laden's 1996 fatwa?

Tags: reference-request, fatwa

For a paper in my Arabic class, I would like to cite from bin Laden's 1996 fatwa "إعلان الحرب ضد الأمريكيين الذين يحتلون أرض الحرمين الشريفين". It would be a little strange to take the English translation and translate back to the original but I can't find the latter; can someone provide tips on how to get it?

Comment: Is it certain that the original was in Arabic?

Comment: It is said to have been published in arabic language newspapers based in London on Wikipedia, and the folks on the history site who initially pointed me here have now indeed produced a (not terribly high quality) scan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already been given an answer on [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/66344). Apparently the title of the document is somewhat different from what you wrote in the question, which could have been why you found it difficult to find it.

Anyways the text is available in better quality and even digitized versions. You should either search for the right title (  إعلان الجهاد على الأمريكيين المحتلين لبلاد الحرمين ) or rather search for snippets of the Arabic text on google, doing so you should be able to find it copied on various websites. For example there is a book titled: أسامة بن لادن مجدد الزمان وقاهر الأمريكان  which compiles the statement (see [pdf - page 396](https://ia600500.us.archive.org/12/items/mojdd014/Uosama_QaherAmrekan.pdf#page=396) or [doc - page 335](https://ia600207.us.archive.org/1/items/ammar_abujaber_hotmail_201601/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9%20%D8%A8%D9%86%20%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%86%20%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D9%88%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86.doc) ).